# Creating unique id for textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

i like to have unique ids for textboxes and hidden filds .is there any property which will give unique id in asp.net ?

something like

`<asp:textbox id="ctr001_1" runat="server" uniqueid="textbox"  />`

Comment: Hi. As stated in my answer provided below, could you tell us why you want to do that so we can provide more help to you?

Comment: Hi. Have you found an answer to your question? Need anymore help? :)

Answer (score 2):

1st thing, why do you need to set the UniqueID property? FYI, ASP.NET web server controls has its own auto-generated readonly UniqueID property that you can access in your coding like below:

```
Textbox1.UniqueID()
```

The UniqueID is generated based on the control hierarchy, and each control's UniqueID property is, obviously, unique.

Comment: If you are using master pages then ASP.Net prepends something to the id so that it is guaranteed to be unique as Gan has pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the TextBox form System.Web.UI.WebControls there you have property UniqueID.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.uniqueid.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Hm, not sure if this is what you are trying to achieve, but try this:

Set an attribute to your control, for example uniqueid="textbox" as you've done, then access the id by myControl.Attributes["uniqueid"].

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET will generate a UniqueID for the both TextBox and HiddenField on the page.  Simply add each tag in markup and specify the ID:

```
<asp:textbox id="TextBox1" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField id="HiddenField1" runat="server" />
```

Both of these values can be accessed in the codebehind by:

```
TextBox1.Text
HiddenField1.Value
```

You can also see their Unquie ClientID by look at:

```
TextBox1.ClientID
HiddenValue1.ClientID
```