# Setting Uniqueid for hidden fild in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am trying to set UniqueID for a hidden field control .its throwing me  error

```
The 'UniqueID' property is read-only and cannot be set.
```

How to solve this issue ??

my code

```
 <asp:HiddenField ID="hSequence" runat="server" UniqueID="hSequence" />
```

Comment: Its better to tell where do you wish to use it.

Comment: i use this inside a repeater.

Comment: my morning dejavu... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545305/creating-unique-id-for-textbox/3545320

Comment: Vash, deja vu indeed! I provided an answer at the link you gave :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define the HiddenField like this:

You can access identifiers from the Server Side like this:

```
hSequence.Value
```

or

```
  Request.Params[hSequence.ClientID]
```

Comment: In my experience, `Request.Params[hSequence.UniqueID]` works better than using the `ClientID`.

Answer (score 0):

Q: You can not to consider to use the ID property as research key for your asp.net controls?

Answer (score 0):

This identifier is generated automatically when a page request is processed.you can just Get it not Set

public virtual string UniqueID { get; }

also see [Control.UniqueID Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.uniqueid.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The UniqueID is auto-generated based on the control hierarchy. You cannot set it. Why do you want to do that anyway? Perhaps we can help you with another solution.